# Hibernate : Does it reload the object after get() with LockOptions.UPGRADE

Tags: hibernate

I'm facing an issue where I'm acquiring a lock on the row using the `get(Serializable,Class,LockOptions)` method with the `LockOptions.UPGRADE`.

The object on which lock is being obtained is already present in the session.
Upon execution of select ... for update, I'm finding that if the corresponding row in table has been changed after the initial fetch of object and before the `get(Serializable,Class,LockOptions)`, the method is not returning an updated object.

I want to clarify following,
 Is this because I'm trying to acquire lock on a row whose object is already loaded in session cache.

Does Hibernate just fires a `select ... for update` in background, but does not reload the object but instead fetches one from the session cache if found?

Following is the code snippet about how I'm acquiring lock.

```
List<MyObject> listOfMyObject = dao.getListOfMyObjects();

for(MyObject m : listOfMyObject ){
   m = session.get(id,MyObject.class,LockOptions.UPGRADE);
   //
}
```

The locking mechanism is working fine. While the lock is being held by lets say ThreadOne transaction, I can see that the other ThreadTwo transaction is waiting to acquire lock. Now when the ThreadOne transaction releases the lock, the second transaction acquires it through `session.get(id,MyObject.class,LockOptions.UPGRADE)` method the object returned does not have the updated value done by ThreadOne.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally when you use LockOptions.Upgrade, its a kind of pessimistic locking.

It shouldn`t ideally  allow any other transaction to come and change the record because it is a kind of pessimistic lock on that database row.

Ideally instead of using pessimistic Locking, go for Optimistic locking by using some kind of version/timestamp column where you have more control programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get(java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable,%20org.hibernate.LockOptions)), `session.get(Serializable,Class,LockOptions)` loads the instance from the session if it already exists. For your situation, you probably want to use `session.refresh(Object object)` right after `session.get(Serializable,Class,LockOptions)` to re-read the state of the instance from the database.